# How to set HDMI card - default audio card

Tags: audio, alsa, hdmi, void-linux, alsamixer

Hello everyone I'm Use laptop + external monitors, and i need use monitor speaker
and i can't see HDMI card in alsamixer,
when reviewing command [ aplay -l ] result =

```
[void@base ~]$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX20757 Analog [CX20757 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [BenQ EX2710]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

and when reviewing command

```
[void@base ~]$  cat /proc/asound/modules
 0 snd_hda_intel
```

other thing : I'm using void-base system and some xorg services and dwm window manager

allright
i need know how to set HDM card to defult audio card

Comment: Default - for what? My guess is that if you have a desktop environment with X, you just use pipewire, which will give you multiple audio streams and the ability to set a default sounds device for applications.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in this case, there is just one audio card (`card 0`), with multiple output devices, one of which is the HDMI output.

---

### PulseAudio/Pipewire

If you use PulseAudio or Pipewire, they should **automatically remember the chosen output device for each audio-producing application if you choose it once**, and for programs that have not produced audio before, they will use whichever output is marked the "fallback" with `pavucontrol` or similar PulseAudio configuration tool.

If you need to do this on the command line, first make sure the correct card profile is used. Use `pactl list cards` to find the card names and the available profiles for each:

```
pactl set-card-profile <card name> <profile name>
```

For HD Audio integrated in an Intel chipset, it would probably be something like:

```
pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3 output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo
```

Then run `pactl list sinks` and find the *sink name* and *port names* for your audio card. In the output, it will look like this:

```
Sink #<sink number>
        State: SUSPENDED
        Name: <here's the sink name you're looking for>
        [...some stuff indented at this level...]
        Properties:
                [...a lot of stuff indented at this level...]
        Ports:
                <here are the port names>
        Active Port: <something>
        Formats:
                [...]
```

Since you apparently have the HD Audio integrated into Intel chipset, the sink name is most likely `alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo`. Then find the names of the ports available for that sink in the `Ports:` section for that sink. It might be something like `hdmi-output-0`.

Once you know the names, you can use them in a commands like this:

```
pactl set-sink-port <sink name or number> <port name>
```

i.e. probably something like this:

```
pactl set-sink-port alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo hdmi-output-0
```

For PulseAudio, you could make it a system-wide default by adding the `set-sink-port` command to `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3 output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo
set-sink-port alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo hdmi-output-0
```

But note that any remembered per-user and per-application settings will normally override the system-wide PulseAudio defaults anyway.

---

### Plain ALSA

If you use just plain ALSA, then you could place something like this in your `~/.asoundrc`:

```
defaults.pcm.!card 0
defaults.ctl.!card 0
defaults.pcm.!device 3
defaults.ctl.!device 3
```

Comment: thanks for that, but i have one problem
void-linux don't use system-d, for that i can't use any command ended by ....ctl

Comment: PulseAudio `pactl` has nothing to do with `systemd`; it comes from `pulseaudio-utils` package. The fact that the name is similar to `systemd` tools is just a coincidence (or maybe shared freedesktop.org practices influencing both). `pactl` also works with Pipewire. Anyway, I also told you how to deal with plain ALSA; Void Linux documentation suggests ALSA, optionally combined with either Pipewire, Pulseaudio or `sndio`. I have no experience on `sndio`; I have covered all I could.

Comment: thanks for help me